# How to remove trailing #! from YouTube ID?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've noticed that some of my users post YouTube links that have a trailing

`#!`

For example

http://youtu.be/VYh9cmCOL5w#!

However my current regex does not remove the `#!` which is causing a host of problems in the video thumbnails.

```
preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\n]+#", $url, $match);
```

Anyone have a suggestions on how to modify my current code to ignore the `#!` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use [`rtrim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
$url = rtrim($url, '#!');
```

Comment: thx @john conde - would this be preferable to removing the `#!` by modifying my existing regex?

Comment: It's simpler and probably faster (although not in meaningful way). But if you can update your regex is would be one less line of code. So it isn't a significantly better one way or another. Do what you feel most comfortable with since you're the one who has to maintain the code. :)

Answer (score 0):

the regex would be

```
\^\(.*?\)\#\!$/
```

then the replacement would be simply

```
\1
```